# Method overloading/overriding in Java subclass object with superclass reference variable

Tags: java, class, inheritance

```
 class A{
 void m1(A a) {System.out.print("A");}
  } 
  class B extends A{
  void m1(B b) {System.out.print("B");}
  } 
  class C extends B{
  void m1(C c) {System.out.print("C");}
  }

 public class d {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  A c1 = new C(); C c2 = new C();c1.m1(c2);

 }}
```

Output of this code is `'A'`.

But if I modify  class A  as:

```
 class A{
 void m1(C a) {System.out.print("A");}
  }
```

then the output is `'C'`. Could somebody please explain how is this code working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(You've made this more confusing than it needs to be by using the same inheritance hierarchy for both the parameter types and the implementation. Separating those would probably help to simplify it in your mind.)

The type of `c1` is `A`. Therefore when working out which *method signature* it's going to call, the compiler can only look at methods declared in `A`.

So in the first case, the compiler is going to call `m1(A)`; in the second case, the compiler is going to call `m1(C)`.

Now in the first case, the `m1(A)` method is never overridden, so actually the execution-time type of `c1` is irrelevant.

In the second case, `m1(C)` is overridden by `C`, so the implementation in `C` is called because the execution-time type of `c1` is `C`.

So remember:

- *Overload* resolution (which method signature is called) is determined at compile-time, based on the compile-time types of both the method target and the argument expressions
- The implementation of that method signature (*overriding*) is based on the actual type of the target object at *execution* time.

Comment: In the first case, c1 is an instance of C. All m1 are instance methods, so why is the compiler calling a method of A when an instance of C is being created?

Comment: @user39929: When the compiler sees `c1.m1` it only cares about the *compile-time* type of `c1`, which is `A`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Did it only took you a 4 minutes to give a concise answer? Awesome.

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic: It's possible that I edited it within 5 minutes of the original answer. But it's not that complicated :)