# Accessing overridden values in child class

Tags: java, class, overriding

Suppose I have an abstract parent class:

```
public abstract class Bar {
    public int count = 0;
}
```

Now I have several concrete subclasses. Suppose one is:

```
public class Foo extends Bar {
    public int count = 1;
}
```

Now I want to iterate through a collection of children extending the abstract class. When I ask their values of `count`, however, I find that what I get is the parent's initialised value, instead of the one initialised in the child:

```
List<Bar> l = new ArrayList<Bar>();
l.add(new Foo());
for (Bar b : l) {
    System.out.println(b.count.toString()); // This always gives 0.
}
```

I am obviously using the class model wrong. What is the correct way so I can get the values initialised by the subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In complement of the Mena's answer, I want to point out that shadowing a superclass attribute in a subclass is often a mess, and clearly not a good object-oriented design.

If you want your `Foo` and `Bar` objects to have different value, why not using a constructor to initialize the `count` field differently ? This is the most straightforward way to achieve your requirement.

```
public class Bar {
  public int count ;

  public Bar() {
    count = 0;
  }
}

public class Foo extends Bar {
  public Foo() {
    count = 1
  }
}
```

With this code, you could easily take advantage of polymorphism to loop over a `List<Bar>` and collect `count`, without having to cast, or without defining a getter for each subclass of `Bar`.

Comment: Completely forgotten about the constructor! Thank you @Mena for the insight but this solved my problem - just don't overshadow!

Answer (score 4):

Your iteration references the type `Bar`, as parametrized type of your `List`.

As such it will get the `count` propery of `Bar`, hidden by `Foo`'s `count`.

That's why you get `0`.

If you want dynamic variable resolution, implement and override a method returning `count`.

Which in turn would help with your encapsulation design if you also set `count` with more appropriate access modifiers.

**Final note**

Quoting your comment:

> I prefer sticking to fields, because I have a lot of these fields

Implementing getters and setters for your fields should be trivial.

In fact, you get automatic drafts or fully implemented methods by just following a quick wizard in any respectable IDE, once you've declared your fields.

As a general rule, you may consider to not use the template getters as is, if your fields are mutable.

As another general rule, you may consider not to use the template setters implemented as is, if your fields require validation before setting.

I suggest for that matter that you have a closer look at the concept of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: I suspected as much. What should I do then? Make it a method? I prefer sticking to fields, because I have a lot of these fields...

Answer (score 1):

[Access to fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25979102/how-does-java-compiler-choose-correct-methods-and-variables-in-inheritance) is resolved at compile time. There is no concept like *fields overriding*, there is only *fields shadowing*: The *count* field in `Foo` shadows the inherited `count` field in `Bar`.

To avoid shadowing and confusion, you should rename the field in the inherited class to `fooCount` for example.

Nevertheless, if you want to print the `count` field defined in `Foo`, you could do:

```
for (Bar b : l) {
    if (b instanceof Foo) {
        System.out.println(((Foo)b).count.toString()); // This always gives 1.
    } else {
        System.out.println(b.count.toString()); // This always gives 0.
    }
}
```

Of course, as suggested in other answers, you should rethink whether this design is good (and the first signal that it may not be good is the usage of `instanceof` operator), and use polymorphism to achieve the same goal in a more readable and maintainable way.